# How do I execute async.map function in order of array contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js, nightmare

I've got the following code routine that works great. The only problem is that I need the results to come back in the same order of the `links` array. For example I need the results of the google.com link to come back first, then yahoo, etc. The code currently returns in a "random" order.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var async = require('async');
var links = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.yahoo.com",
    "http://www.bing.com",
    "http://www.aol.com",
    "http://duckduckgo.com",
    "http://www.ask.com"
  ];

var scrape = function(url, callback) {
  var nightmare = new Nightmare();
  nightmare.goto(url);
  nightmare.wait('body');
  nightmare.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector('body').innerText;
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(url, result);
  })
  nightmare.end(function() {
    callback();
  });
}

async.map(links, scrape);
```

UPDATE:
Thanks @christophetd. Here is my revised working code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var async = require('async');
var links = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.yahoo.com",
    "http://www.bing.com",
    "http://www.aol.com",
    "http://duckduckgo.com",
    "http://www.ask.com"
  ];

var scrape = function(url, callback) {
  var nightmare = new Nightmare();
  nightmare.goto(url);
  nightmare.wait('body');
  nightmare.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector('body').innerText;
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    callback(null, url+result);
  });
  nightmare.end();
}

async.map(links, scrape, function (err, results) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: what you describe is not async... can you re-order them once you have them all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the official async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) :

> the results array will be in the same order as the original collection

Which is pretty easy to verify:

```
// This function waits for 'number' seconds, then calls cb(null, number)
var f = function (number, cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(null, number)
    }, number * 1000)
}

async.map([4, 3, 2, 1], f, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results); // [4, 3, 2, 1]
})
```

As you can see in the code above, even if the processing of the argument `4` by `f` takes more time than the element `3`, it will still be first in the results.

---

In the case of your code, writing:

```
async.map(links, scrape, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error, don't forget to return
    }
    // results will be in the same order as 'links'
})
```

Should give you the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect. I had seen the answer you referenced in the docs, but for some reason it didn't make sense until I saw your answer.